# Error Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have this error message :

```
com.example.faizirrahmadi.eyeglauapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.faizirrahmadi.eyeglauapp, PID: 22114
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.faizirrahmadi.eyeglauapp/com.example.faizirrahmadi.eyeglauapp.PenyakitActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
    at com.example.faizirrahmadi.eyeglauapp.PenyakitActivity.prepareListData(PenyakitActivity.java:111)
    at com.example.faizirrahmadi.eyeglauapp.PenyakitActivity.onCreate(PenyakitActivity.java:69)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

And here is my code (java class)

```
package com.example.faizirrahmadi.eyeglauapp;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import sistempakar.dbHelper;

 /**
 * Created by Faizir Rahmadi on 3/19/2016.
 */
 public class PenyakitActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
 ExpandableListView expListView;
 List<String> listDataHeader;
 HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

 Cursor cursor_gejala;
 dbHelper myDb;
 SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase;
 TextView nama_penyakit;


 public String bundleId;
 public String bundleKode;
 private String bundleNamaPenyakit;
 private String bundleDeskripsi;
 private String bundleGejala;
 private String bundlePenanganan;
 String a;

List<String> bundleNamaGejala;
List<String> namaGejalaList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_penyakit);

    Bundle takeData = getIntent().getExtras();
    bundleId = takeData.getString("clickedId");
    bundleKode = takeData.getString("clickedKode").toLowerCase();
    bundleNamaPenyakit = takeData.getString("clickedNamaPenyakit");
    bundleDeskripsi = takeData.getString("clickedDeskripsi");
    bundleGejala = takeData.getString("clickedGejala");
    bundlePenanganan = takeData.getString("clickedPenanganan");

    //mengubah kode gejala menjadi nama gejala yang ditampilkan
    bundleNamaGejala = Arrays.asList(bundleGejala.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

    nama_penyakit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    nama_penyakit.setText(bundleNamaPenyakit);
    nama_penyakit.setAllCaps(true);


    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    namagejala(bundleNamaGejala);
    a = new String(TextUtils.join(", ", namaGejalaList));
    prepareListData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    Toast.makeText(this, a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//mengubah kode gejala dalam tabel RELASI menjadi nama gejala dari tabel GEJALA
public List<String> namagejala(List<String> _nama) {
    myDb = new dbHelper(this);
    sqliteDatabase = myDb.getReadableDatabase();
    String where = "";
    namaGejalaList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _nama.size(); i++) {
        where = where + dbHelper.COLUMN_ID_GEJALA + " IN('" + _nama.get(i).toString() + "')";
        if (i != (_nama.size() - 1)) {
            where = where + " OR ";
        }
    }
    cursor_gejala = sqliteDatabase.query(dbHelper.TABLE_GEJALA, new String[]{dbHelper.COLUMN_NM_GEJALA}, where, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor_gejala.moveToNext()) {
        namaGejalaList.add(cursor_gejala.getString(cursor_gejala.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.COLUMN_NM_GEJALA)));
    }
    return namaGejalaList;
}

private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    listDataHeader.add("Gejala");


    List<String> deskripsi = new ArrayList<String>();
    deskripsi.add(bundleDeskripsi);

    List<String> gejala = new ArrayList<String>();
    gejala.add(a);

    List<String> penanganan = new ArrayList<String>();
    penanganan.add(bundlePenanganan);

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), deskripsi);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), gejala);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), penanganan);
}

}
```

I don't know how this could happend.. i have check and always there's error on `prepareListData();` and `listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), gejala);`
I've been searching all the answer and nothing could help me
Thank you for your kindess for helping me and solve this problem for the future

Answer (score 0):

List index starts from 0, so if you want get first element, you should write

```
listDataHeader.get(0)
```

If the size of listDataHeader is 1, you will have an exception when you try to get element with index 1.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you put one item in your

```
listDataHeader.add("Gejala");
```

in **prepareListData()** method. Which is on **0** index. And you are trying to access

```
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), gejala);
```

index **1** of **listDataHeader** list which is not available. So, you get the error.